# How can i get auto generated id from JSON in reactJS or C#

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

how can i get auto generated id from this object in an array 
thank you

```
{
    "CourseList": {
        "-Lti4CFDdJwAkBW5ujqm": {  //auto generated id
            "a1_courseName": "robotics",
            "a2_courseCode": "1212"
        },
        "-LtrpJSDN4OCQAyJiSmQ": {  //auto generated id
            "a1_courseName": "shsh",
            "a2_courseCode": "hhshs"
        }
    },
    "PersonalInfo": {
        "email": "arifulis@******.edu",
        "teacherInstitute": "####",
        "teacherName": "arif"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more

Comment: Convert `json` to c# class. Deserialize above object using that class. You will get plenty of questions on stack overflow like this.

Comment: You have tagged this question [tag:c#] and [tag:reactjs].  Are you looking for an answer using c# or using javascript?

Comment: @dbc yes, any of them

Comment: @SushantYelpale it gives me null, bcz key name is unknown.

Comment: @MdArifulIslam - You're more likely to get an answer if you specify the required language.  Let's say someone answers in c# and someone else in Javascript; you can only [accept one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the other answer gets ignored and the writer ends up wasting their time.  You might want to take the [tour] and read [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Yes, this will deserialize as a dictionary and you can get the `Keys` collection as your id list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with [NewtonSoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), generate it as Dictionary,

```
public partial class CourseAndnfo
{
   public Dictionary<string, CourseList> CourseList { get; set; }
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get; set; }
}

public partial class CourseList
{
    public string a1_courseName { get; set; }
    public string a2_courseCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonalInfo
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TeacherInstitute { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize it using,

```
var ParsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CourseAndInfo>(Yourjson);
List<string> AutoGeneratedIds = ParsedJson.CourseList.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: Not my question. Just my advice